# Cannot Detect Margin with JavaScript DOM While It Is Set in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, dom, margin

Cannot Detect Margin with JavaScript DOM While It Is Set in CSS:

```
<div>
  <div id="elem">

  </div>
</div>


#elem{
   margin:0;   
}

console.log(document.getElementById('elem').style.marginLeft)     //""
console.log(document.getElementById('elem').style["margin-left"]) //undefined
console.log($('#elem').css('margin-left'))                        //0px
```

What's wrong? 
What is the bullet-proof way to certainly detect margin without setting it via DOM? 
Why does jQuery detect?
Can anyone explain in technical details why margin cannot be detected so I have an understanding?

http://jsfiddle.net/SBznP/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remember, that CSS and DOM are different parts. Changes in CSS won't change DOM content and vice-versa.

This means, that `element.style.marginLeft` (DOM) returns the current value of the `style` attribute's `marginLeft` property.

Using `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, '').getPropertyValue('margin-left')` you can get the computed value instead.

PS: That last way is -sadly- not compatible with some of the older browsers. You might be interested in a cross-browser version: http://cross-browser.com/x/lib/view.php?s=xGetComputedStyle